# How to fix 'CS0246' error in Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, cs0246

I have a web page using Entity Framework that stopped working.  I'm rebuilding it in VS2017.  I have no errors when compiling, but when accessing the webpage I get:

---

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ausoftus_dbEntities1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 16: 
Line 17: 
Line 18:     ausoftus_dbEntities1 db = new ausoftus_dbEntities1();

---

My EF is called 'Patriots'.  If I encapsulate the function in a namespace in Patriots.Context.cs, my code also compiles fine referencing that namespace.  But the web page returns the error that it can't find the namespace.

I checked that my project uses the same .Net version as the EF.  The project properties shows Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1.  I'm using EF 6.2.

In Patriots.Context.cs (within App_Code folder):

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class ausoftus_dbEntities1 : DbContext
{
    public ausoftus_dbEntities1()
        : base("name=ausoftus_dbEntities1")
    {
    }
```

How do I make sure that System.Data.Entity is the right version?

Comment: The way you solve this problem is the same as the way you solve it everywhere else: by resolving the broken references.  Most of the solution is described in the error message itself.  I doubt that the version of System.Data.Entity you're using is the actual problem.

Comment: The reference isn't broken in VS, so I don't seen anything to resolve.  How does one 'resolve the broken reference"?

Comment: Are you missing a `using` directive?

Comment: I don't have any errors in VS.  What would I use, anyway? System.Data.Entity?  When I add that, it says that it's unnecessary.  ausoftus_dbEntities1 is declared in Patriots.Context.cs.  Using doesn't allow the class name in my default.aspx.cs file.  As stated above, if you put a namespace in Patriots.Context.cs I can add a 'using' with the namespace, but then I get the 0246 for the using declaration.  It's as if the published location can't find the EF files.

Comment: Are you properly distributing EF with your application?

Comment: I've published my project, the EF files and EntityFramework.dll.  Searching for 'distributing EF' to see what I'm missing.